# Padding wrong when presenting second modal navigation controller on iOS 13

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios13, uinavigationitem

On iOS 13, when presenting a second modal view controller over a first one, the padding is incorrect on the button bar items.  In particular, the right margin disappears.

[image: Incorrect Padding]

How should this be fixed?

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is due to a bug in iOS 13.  It can be fixed by calling setNeedsLayout on the Navigation Bar.

Swift example:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {  
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)  
     if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {  
          navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()  
     }  
}
```

Objective-C example:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // Fix navigation item placement on iOS 13: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121861
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsLayout];
    }
}
```

Credits: Solution borrowed from [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121861) on the Apple Developer Form.

Comment: Also from that thread on Apple Developer Forum, it only worked for me using:
self.view.layoutIfNeeded() inside viewWillAppear:animated